# What is linux-image-5.14.0-1032-oem kernel? There is no LTS kernel 5.14 on the kernel.org site

Tags: 20.04, kernel

What is linux-image-5.14.0-1032-oem kernel in the 20.04 repository? There is no LTS kernel 5.14 on the kernel.org site. Is it a LTS kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linux-image-5.14.0-1032-oem is NOT a kernel. It is a meta package and belongs to a 3rd party repository from the Canonical Kernel Team

As the launchpad for this PPA states:

"This ppa is used for building pre-release and test kernels. It IS NOT RECOMMENDED that you subscribe to this PPA."

Comment: When I enter command 'sudo apt install linux-image' this meta package appears in the list. I am not subscribed to that PPA.